# Add non duplicates numbers into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a function in javaScript that checks if it is the first time the numbers has been seem, if so, it will be added to the the array. For some reason the first number is always repeating it, Ex:

if we pass [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
it will print out [1,1,2,3,4,5] instead of [1,2,3,4,5]

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing ?? 
Thank you in advance.

```
var numbers = [1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,8];
function eliminateDup(arr){

    var myArr = [];

    for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){

        if(!myArr[arr[i]]){

            myArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return myArr;
}
console.log(eliminateDup(numbers));
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just use `indexOf` instead of this mess: `!myArr[arr[i]]`

Comment: Note that you can do all that with `uniques = [...new Set(numbers)]`

Comment: This assumes the input is sorted ascending

Comment: @ASDFGerte, neither is true.

Comment: OK, we have four (oh wait, we've got five) answers now suggesting `indexOf`. Maybe someone can be a bit more original?

Comment: @trincot why dont you explain your first comment as an answer

Comment: Because it really is a duplicate.

Comment: @trincot elaborate please, i had to think about the ascending part because it wasn't enough, it needs to be ascending and not omitting any numbers. The zero based part was also not enough, the offset is `arr[0]` as in `if(!myArr[arr[i] - arr[0]]){` but won't work for anything greater than 1. Explicitly, if you push an eight to the numbers in the posted example, it will also get doubled in the result because the seven was omitted.

Comment: The whole idea of `!myArr[arr[i]]` is wrong for one reason: it uses array *values* as *indexes*, while the two are completely different concepts and have nothing to do with eachother. This has nothing to do with sort-order or zero-based. Imagine an input array with `[500, 600, 700]`.

Answer (score 1):

This comparison doesn't make sense :

```
if(!myArr[arr[i]]){
```

It is `true` only if `!myArr[arr[i]]` can be converted to `true`.
You get twice `1` in the target array `myArr`  because both `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` equals to `1` and `myArr` has an undefined element at the `1` index for the two first iterations at the time where the conditional statement is executed.

---

**First iteration**

```
i = 0 
arr[0] = 1
myArr[1] = undefined
```

So  `if(!myArr[1])` is `true`.
You add `1`.

**Second iteration**

```
i = 1     
arr[1] = 1
myArr[0] = 1 // now valued but not used in the test
myArr[1] = undefined;
```

So  `if(!myArr[1])` is `true`.
You still add `1`.

**Third iteration**

```
i = 2
arr[2] = 1
myArr[0] = 1 
myArr[1] = 1
```

So  `if(!myArr[1])` is `false`.
nothing is added.

---

You should rather check whether the current value is not contained in the target array before adding it in the target array :

```
if(myArr.indexOf(arr[i])==-1){
    myArr.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this condition instead, for push

```
if(myArr.indexOf([arr[i])===-1)
```

Comment: thank you so much guys, as a beginner I'm struggling sometimes to debug my own codes. it mades complete sense what you all have explained to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`myArr.push(arr[i]);` will push to back of the array `myArr` (just like a stack) and thus element '1' will be at index 0.

`myArr[arr[i]]` checks if element at index `arr[i]` exists which it won't so *will push another 1*.

As suggested above use `indexof()` which will just search and give an index if the element exists.